# Grails validation no Constraints block

Tags: validation, grails

The usual way of constraint validating domain objects in Grails is by defining a static constraints closure in the domain object, after which one can call myObject.validate().

Is it possible in some way to pass what should be validated to the validate call and not define a constraints block?

I guess it could be done with Spring validator instances, but is there an easier way where you still have the "goodies" from Grails (max, email, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of fields into `.validate(["fieldA", "fieldB"])` and it will only validate those fields. You still need a constraints block to define what the constraints are for those fields.

From Grails User Guide:
"*The validate method accepts an optional List argument which contains the names of the properties to be validated. When a List of names is specified, only those properties will be validated.*"

To respond to @eugene82:

```
@Validateable
class MyDomainValidator {
String email
static constraints = {
email(email:true)
}
}

MyDomain m = new MyDomain()...
MyDomainValidator mv = new MyDomainValidator()..
mv.properties = m.properties
mv.validate()
```

Comment: Then I don't understand your question

Comment: Well, my question states: "no constraints block" - even in th subject. You are suggesting I use constraint blocks.. So.. Go figure :)

Comment: My answer did answer your question because you need a constraints block if you want to use the built in validation. Period.

Comment: Nice argumentation. Period!

Answer (score -1):

I imagine such an approach: Create a `@Validateable` groovy class with static constraints inside with any Grails goodies you need. Let it own all fields like your domain does (e.g. by extending the domain), and provide a way to copy all fields from a domain instance to a new instance of that object, e.g. using a constructor. Than call `validate()` on that class.

```
class MyDomain {
    String email
    MyDomain() {}
    MyDomain(email) {
        email = this.email
    }
}
@Validateable
class MyDomainCustomValidator extends MyDomain {
    MyDomainValidator() {}
    MyDomainValidator(domain) {
        super(domain.email)
    }
    static constraints = {
        email email: true
    }
}

def d = new MyDomain('e@mail.com')
new MyDomainCustomValidator(d).validate()
```

Comment: Well.. It is not quite what I am looking for. I would rather be able to do something like d.validate(thisConstraint). I dont know if it is possible at all...

Comment: @James, why? Is there another way to apply to a domain any Grails constraints defined outside of that domain?